# How can I prove that $A \setminus (B \setminus C) \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I found the Venn Diagram of the relation using Wolfram so I know this is a true statement. I'm lost on how to prove it though.

[Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFJgk.png)

I'm thinking of going with the $x \in A \setminus (B \setminus C)$ method but I don't know what to do after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)$. By definition, we have that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\setminus C$.

Suppose $x\notin C$. Then, $x\notin C\cup (B\setminus C)$, so since $B\subseteq C\cup(B\setminus C)$, we have $x\notin B$. Thus, $x\in A\setminus B$.

Thus, $A\setminus (B\setminus C)\subseteq (A\setminus B)\cup C$.